# Solspace Rating: how can I display the most recent ratings?

Tags: ee2, solspace-rating

I have Solspace Rating 3.2.4 installed; and while I'm seeing examples to [show the most popular/highest ratings](http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/rank/#examples), I want to show the ten most recent ratings (that is, the ten most recent ratings that have received at least one vote.) The output and formatting in the linked example is fine; it's just the sorting of which ratings are displayed, that is different from what I want. Am I looking at the wrong tag, to generate a list of the ten most recent ratings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{exp:rating:entries}` tag and sort by date. I'm not sure how you'd filter out those that don't have at least one vote though.

Comment: I found out how to exclude the unrated ones - there's a variable on the exp:rating:entries tag. (Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!) Now, though, if I want to display the entry link and title of each rating, how do I do that? Nest the exp:channel:entries tag inside of the exp:rating:entries tag?

Comment: I think channel entries tags like {title} and {url_title} work inside {exp:rating:entries} without any additional tags.

Comment: They do - yay! I wonder why the documentation doesn't list that these parameters will work...? Maybe it's somewhere else in the documentation; but it would be great if they could somehow call that out in the documentation. Thanks for your assistance!